Proving that any closed connected subgroup of a torus is again a torus
I am currently trying to prove that any closed connected subgroup of a torus is again a torus. Up to now here is what I found:
Suppose that I have a torus $G=\mathbb{T}^n$ (viewed as a product of circle in the complex plane) and $N$ is a closed (hence also compact) Lie subgroup of $G$. I proved earlier that, given a fairly standard basis of the Lie algebra of $G$, then the exponential map is simply given by
\begin{equation}
exp(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)=(e^{i\theta_1},...,e^{i\theta_n}).
\end{equation}
This gives us a nice way to see that $G=\frac{\mathbb{R}^n}{(2\pi\mathbb{Z})^n}$.
I also found a nice blog page from Terence Tao (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/, though there might be easier way to prove this I don't really know to be honest) that mentions the fact that if a Lie group is compact and connected then the exponential map is always surjective.
Therefore, my idea was the following: I know that the exponential map of $N$ is simply the restriction of the exponential map of $G$, onto its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{n}$. By the 'Terrence Tao's blog page property', the exponential map $exp_N$ of $N$ is therefore also surjective so that if I denote $d=$dim$(N)$, then, $N=\frac{\mathbb{R}^d}{ker(exp_N)}$. My question are therefore: 1) Is this a good start ?
2) If yes, how am I supposed to prove that the kernel of $exp_N$ is also some nice lattice?
Thank you in advance if you can guide me through this!

Notice that $\ker(\exp_N)$ is the intersection $\ker (\exp) \cap \mathfrak{n}$, in particular it is a subgroup of $\ker (\exp)$ which is a discrete subgroup in the Lie algebra of $G$, so $\ker(\exp_N)$ is a discrete subgroup of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{n} \simeq \Bbb R^d$. There are now two options:

either $\ker(\exp_N)$ is a full lattice inside $\Bbb R^d$, in which case the quotient $\Bbb R^d / \ker(\exp_N)$ is indeed a torus ;
or $\ker(\exp_N)$ does not generate $\Bbb R^d$, hence $\Bbb R^d / \ker(\exp_N)$ is non-compact (and in particular, not a torus).

One of the assumptions on $N$ can discriminate between these two options. Can you see what it is ?

Thank you very much for your quick answer! I do understand why the second possibilty cannot be correct (N is closed in a compact topological space and hence compact). However, I am not really sure to understand the dichotomy, how is the second possibilty equivalent to "ker($exp_n$) is not a lattice" ? I have the intuition that either the intersection is a lattice or either it is the empty set, is that possible ?

@AilanMaichattaSmithee it could be that $\ker(\exp_N)$ is a free abelian group of rank $<d$ inside $\Bbb R^d$, or even empty. For instance, consider the usual torus $\Bbb T^2$, view it as the square $[0,1]^2$ with glued edges. Now, look at the subgroup $H$ given by a line of irrational slope in the square, which wraps around infinitely: this subgroup is nonclosed (it is in fact dense in the torus). You can check for youself that in this case, $\ker(\exp_N)$ is empty, and $H$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ (! as an abstract group, but not as a topological group !): torsion free, so no torus.

Ok I get it ! Thank you very much for your time !
